# Making sense out of the method for finding posterior distributions.

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, statistical-inference, bayesian

I have been recently studying Bayesian statistics and more precisely the problem of finding posterior distributions. I am able to understand the my textbook's problems, but I realize that I understand the issue on cookbook level. This is why I would like to ask a question, which I found and hope to get better insight.

The problem is:
Suppose we are interested in finding the mean value of the velocity of a large number of particles. We draw and measure a sample of size $N$ and get a sample mean value of 70m/s. We assume that the population mean is normally distributed with an unknown mean $\mu$ and std. deviation 10 m/s. The prior distribution of the mean $\mu$ is a normal distribution with mean 100m/s and st. deviation 20m/s.

The question is how to get the posterior as a function of the sample size $N$

The prior distributions should be

$$
P(\mu)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \cdot 20^2 \pi}}\exp{\left(-\frac{(\mu-100)^2}{2 \cdot 20^2}\right)}
$$
The next step is to define the likelihood.Since we are interested in a function of sample size $N$  my guess is to use the expression for the sample standard deviation
$$
\sigma_{\overline{x}}=\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{N}}
$$

The sample mean is $\mu_{\overline{x}}=70$, this should yield for the likelihood

$$
P(\mu_{\overline{x}}=70|\mu)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \cdot \frac{10^2}{N} \pi}}\exp{\left(-\frac{(\mu-70)^2}{2 \cdot \frac{10^2}{N}}\right)}
$$

This should give us for the posterior expression of the sort
$$
P(\mu|\mu_{\overline{x}}=70) = P(\mu_{\overline{x}}=70|\mu) \cdot P(\mu)
$$
Or in other words the posterior gives the probability to have population mean $\mu$ if we had $\mu_{\overline{x}}=70$.
I fear that my argument is faulty, I am not sure. 
Would appreciate your help.

Comment: Your expression for the posterior distribution seems to lack a denominator.

Comment: @JohnColeman I think that the denominator integrates to unity. The denominator in this case represents the probability to have $\mu_{\overline{x}}=70$, which we know is true.

Comment: The denominator doesn't integrate to 1. How could it? Bayes theorem states that $P(A|B) = P(A \cap B) / P(B)$ not $P(A|B) = P(A \cap B) / P(B|B)$. The denominator isn't conditioned by the given event -- it is the *probability* of that event.

Comment: @JohnColeman because you know already that you measured $\mu_{\overline{x}}=70$ . That is said from the very beginning. Hence the probability is one, quite obvious. What you typed is the formula for two events occurring if they are dependent, check Wikipedia to see how it relates to prior,posterior and likelihood.

Comment: Read what I said more carefully. Posterior distributions are *always* conditional -- but the denominator isn't  always 1 (in fact, it almost never is). If your argument were valid, it would hold for all cases. You don't compute the denominator under the assumption that the given event has happened. In Bayes Theorem the denominator is P(B) -- you *don't* say "we are assuming B hence P(B) = 1, quite obviously".

Comment: @JohnColeman what you wrote is not the formula for finding the posterior. What you use in the case of the posterior is $P(A \cdot B) = P(B \cdot A)$. Expand this and you would see that you miss some terms. And yes the denominator is 1, because you have the result form the measurement.

Comment: What is your understanding of the denominator in the formula for a posterior density? The *point* of computing a posterior is that you are trying to understand the distribution of a parameter given some observed data. Your argument, if valid, suggests that the integral in the denominator is always 1. That isn't true. If you are skeptical, take your expression (with e.g. N = 200 for numerical convenience) and see if it integrates to 1. The denominator is a normalizing factor needed to make sure that numerator integrates to 1. You seem to claim that this normalizing factor is 1. Why not try it?

Comment: By the way, the key observation here is that you are dealing with *conjugate priors* -- so the posterior that you are looking for is also normally distributed. You can't ignore the denominator, but you don't need to literally integrate it. You can find the mean and the variance of the posterior by multiplying the exponentials that you (correctly) gave together and then completing the square. N will play a role in this, which is what the question is looking for.

Comment: @JohnColeman what is your suggestion, what should the denominator be equal to.

Comment: There is no need to explicitly work out what the denominator is -- the answer that you gave is *proportional* to the right answer, and the right answer is normal. Look at what you have -- can you pick out the mean and the variance? Use laws of exponents followed by completing the square. Or -- just use the result of doing the algebra once and for all -- look at the first entry in the chart for continuous distributions here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_prior (and note that the sum of the `xi` that appears in the formula is `70N` in your problem statement).

Comment: @JohnColeman well exactly, the denominator is not important. I know how to work out the product the question is whether in my expression for $P(\mu_{\overline{x}}=70|\mu)$ I should use the standard deviation of the mean. That is my big doubt.